# Does this require a JAR file?

Tags: java, logging

I get this error when I tried copying, pasting and compiling using TextPad:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Jon\Desktop\DesHelper.java:10: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
    private static org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(DesHelper.class);
                            ^
C:\Documents and Settings\Jon\Desktop\DesHelper.java:10: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
    private static org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(DesHelper.class);
                                                   ^
2 errors
```

Comment: You are missing the slf4j jar.

Answer (score 1):

jepp. You can either comment all the log statements in the code (please dont) or add the slf4j.jar to the classpath. get it from here: http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

another way (if iuts your code anyway) would be to use the logging that is part of the JDK. slf4j is a logging facade for mutliple logging frameworks (commons-logging, log4j, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing slf4j library from your classpath. To resolve the issue:

1) Download slf4j.jar from http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

2) Put it in `C:\Documents and Settings\Jon\Desktop\`

3) Run `javac -cp slf4j.jar DesHelper.java`. (The name of the jar might change based on version)